# How to extract individual CSS filter functions from an element's style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-filters

I have an image on my HTML page with some filters applied to it. Its `style` attribute might look like this:

```css
filter: brightness(85%) contrast(136%) saturate(122%) drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000000) grayscale(25%)
```

What I want to do is to extract individual style functions from this string, and store them into an object or an array, like:

```js
{ "brightness": "80%", "contrast": "136%" /* and so on ... */ }
```

or:

```js
[["brightness", "80%"], ["contrast", "136%"] /* and so on ... */ ]
```

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using `jQuery`? Also, are the styles set directly onto the elements in their `style=` attribute, or are you using css?

Comment: @Martin 1. I'm using vanilla JS, no jQuery. 2. The filters are specified in the `style` attribute of the element. Classes are not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. get the value of the filter in css as a string
2. get the position of every filter in the styles string
3. get the array of filters and the position in the styles string
4. order the previous array by the index (the position)
5. build the pairs filter, value.

I hope this is what you are asking for.

```js
let para = document.querySelector('p');// the filtered element
let s = window.getComputedStyle(para);//get the style for the filtered element
let theFilter = s.getPropertyValue("filter");//get the value of the filter
// the array of all the filters in css
let filters = ["blur","brightness","contrast","drop-shadow","grayscale","hue-rotate","invert","opacity","saturate","sepia","url"];
// an empty array 
let ry = [];

filters.forEach((f,i)=>{
  let oF = theFilter.match(f);
  if(oF){
    ry.push({prop:oF[0],index:oF.index})
  }
})

// ry is the array of the filters and the position in theFilter string [{prop: "brightness", index: 0},{prop: "contrast", index: 17}...

function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a.index - b.index;
}
// order the ry array by index
let sortedry = ry.sort(compareNumbers);


// the object with the filters
let oFilters = {}

for(let i = 0; i < sortedry.length; i++){
  let sbstr = (i+1 < sortedry.length) ? theFilter.substring(sortedry[i].index,sortedry[i+1].index).trim() : theFilter.substring(sortedry[i].index).trim()
  let value = sbstr.substring(sbstr.indexOf("(")+1, sbstr.length-1);
  oFilters[sortedry[i].prop] = value;
}

console.log(oFilters)
```

```css
p{filter: brightness(85%) contrast(136%) saturate(122%) drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000000) grayscale(25%)}
```

```html
<p>The filtered element</p>
```

Comment: Useful answer for me